# Replace space with underscore in Netbeans Code Templates

Tags: javascript, regex, netbeans-7, code-templates

I created the below **JavaScript Code Template** in Netbeans 7.1.1
This is to generate code automatically in the editor, instead of typing it.

```
do_this('${selection}${cursor}',13)
```

which will result in the below code, with the cursor between quotes

```
do_this('',13)
```

The template automatically places the text I have highlighted, between quotes.

Now, the problem:  I would like to replace any spaces within the selected/highlighted piece of code, with underscores.  I think this may be possible with Regular Expressions (regex), however I am not sure how to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Netbeans specific stuff, but once you have the selection you could do something like this:

```
selection = selection.split(" ").join("_");
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case its basically a shortcut to generate code instead of typing it.  Not a matter of data in a variable.

Comment: Sure, I just didn't understand your question. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in NetBeans Code Templates, as they do not have any functions to manipulate the data in variables.  If I have a work around for it, I will post it here.

Thanks.